# ng-repeat value in array with same name

Tags: arrays, json, angular, angularjs-ng-repeat

In my array there is multiple key value having same name . I want to list them all in my View how can I achieve that ?

I am facing error stating `[ngRepeat:dupes] Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed`.

**This is my JSON array** :-

```
["text-align", "space-before", "space-before.conditionality", "font-size", "font-weight", "line-height", "font-size", "font-weight", "line-height", "space-before", "font-size", "font-weight", "line-height", "position", "top", "bottom", "right", "left", "text-align", "force-page-count", "break-before", "font-size"]
```

As we can see few keys are repeating . I need to list all repeated values without missing any in my View

Comment: use track by https://plnkr.co/edit/u4nbIJztVaRvEmCqTvCs?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You you use `ng-repeat` it loops over the unique values in the array. If you have duplicate values then you need to explicitly mention the Angular module to ignore the values to be unique and look for unique `index` value, by doing:

```
ng-repeat = "item in items track by $index"
```

Using `track by` you can explicitly mention that which value should be checked as a uniqueness measure while rendering the DOM using `ng-repeat`. You can even use the property of the object like `item in items track by item.id` where `item` is a object having `id` property and `items` is a array of objects.

Your array has `font-size` specified multiple times in the array so use `track by $index`.

Comment: I may have blank value in the array .. I want to filter that out . how can I do that ?like `["text-align", "space-before"," ", " ", "font"]`

Comment: @WhoAmI you need to ask a new question for that

Answer (score 1):

You can use `track by $index` to remove this error, something like this

```
<tag ng-repeat="item in items  track by $index">

//content

</tag>
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat